# C# - Xamarin forms remove listview item on toggle

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms

So, I want to remove the item in my listview that I toggled. I have a listview like this:

[image: Result]

Now I want that when I click something to be selected, that it will be removed from the listview, but the users must have a pop-up prompted first in which states if the user is really sure if the item can be deleted.

Here is my code that I have now:

```
private async void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            Tasks task = (sender as Switch).BindingContext as Tasks;
            await ApiManager.UpdateTasksFromListAsync(task);
        }
```

This just updates a value on the API. But how can I remove/hide it from the listview?

This is the xaml code:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvwDetailPage" SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Switch IsToggled="{Binding completed}" Grid.Column="0" Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding title}" TextColor="#212121" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0" />

                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: you remove it from the ItemsSource the ListView is using

Comment: And how can I do this?

Comment: Need to see what you are assigning to your `lvwDetailPage` `ListView.ItemSource`. Are you assigning a `List` to it directly or using binding?

Comment: So I do `lvwDetailPage.ItemsSource = tasks;` and task is a array of all the `Tasks` So I'm assigning it directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    ObservableCollection<Tasks> TaskList;

    private async Task GetData(long id)
    {
        List<Tasks> tasks = await ApiManager.GetTasksFromListAsync(id);

        TaskList = new ObservableCollection<Tasks>(tasks);

        lvwDetailPage.ItemsSource = TaskList;

        lvwDetailPage.ItemSelected += LvwDetailPage_ItemSelected;
    }

    private async void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        Tasks task = (sender as Switch).BindingContext as Tasks;

        if (task != null)
        {
            await ApiManager.UpdateTasksFromListAsync(task);
            TaskList.Remove(task);
        }          
    }
```

Comment: I don't have an `ObservableCollection<Task>`, the thing here is, I get the data using this code: https://pastebin.com/x9qa9nQf and the class `Tasks` just contains the Json format (from the API).

Comment: lvwDetailPage.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Task>(tasks);

Comment: Use Tasks instead of Task.

Comment: Okey, but how am I supposed to do `TaskList.Remove(task);` if I don't have any `TaskList`?

Comment: you just save a reference to it - this is pretty basic C#.  See my expanded example

Comment: Now, I have the code implemented that you provided me with, but my app crashes, when I try to remove an item